# How to Find, Partition, and Format Unmounted HD

Tags: 20.04, hardware

I recently build a new PC with a Seagate 2TB Barracuda HDD for local storage and a page disk.  I installed Ubuntu 20.04.  I am unable to access the Seagate disk, and I'm looking for information on how to partition and format the drive.

I also have a 1TB SSDD with the OS installed, so the system works.  The problem is that I cannot see the Seagate HDD.

Comment: Well, starting with the obvious, check your power cord to the disk to assure that it is connected and has power.  If the drive has an on/off switch, check that.  Check the USB (or other) cable to assure that it is connected securely.  Try looking for it with GParted to see if it has a partition and is formatted.  If you can see the disk but just not access it, try accessing it from the root account - maybe privileges are blocking you from seeing it.  That's all I can think of at the moment. Is the disk old? Maybe it has failed.

Comment: The disk is brand new.  It's on a PCI bus.  It is connected electrically.  I have used several programs (fdisk, sfdisk, cfdisk, parted, df, pydf, lsblk, blkid, hwinfo) to try and see it.  If it's in there, I can't see it.  I have two other disks.  A Western Digital solid state disk drive, and a USB Buffalo drive.  They show up.  I just cannot seem to find the Seagate HD.

Comment: Some disks have jumper settings for "master/slave" and possibly for "cable select."  The way the jumpers are set can affect whether the drive is visible to the system or not.  Look at the documentation that came with your hard drive for instructions on how to set the jumpers.  You might also have to change the jumper setting for the other hard drive if it is on the same ribbon cable.  Make sure the system is powered down when you change jumper settings.

Comment: Ok, for my own clarification: I don't know what SSDD is unless it's a typo for SSD, which is a solid state drive.  That is probably a USB drive, am I correct?  And the Buffalo drive is a USB drive.  So your Barracuda HDD is the only PCI drive in the system, if I understand correctly.  In that case, you should set your Seagate Barracuda's jumpers to "Master" because it is the only drive on the cable.  Once you do that, the system should be able to see your drive.  Then you can partition and format it with GParted or another partition editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, much of this confusion was my fault.  I can now see the Seagate HD.  The answer was in the BIOS.  I have an ASUS Aura Sync TUF Gaming Z490-Plus (WI-FI) motherboard.
While booting, press F2 to enter the BIOS.  Press F7 to enter advanced mode.  Select "Advanced" from the menu on top.  Select "PCH Storage Configuration".  Select "SATA Mode Selection".  (I mistakenly thought the HD was on a PCIe bus.  As I understand it, the Seagate HDD is designed for the SATA bus only, so no jumper is involved.)  By default the SATA Mode Selection is "Intel RST Premium With Intel Optane System Acceleration (RAID)).  I changed it to ACHI.  I can now see the Seagate HD in gparted.
My use of SSDD was my inexperience with solid state drives.  I read an article which used that acronym when referring to a solid state drive.  As I understand it now, the SSD acronym is commonly used.  Again, my mistake.
Happy day, I can now see the drive using gparted.  Thanks, Stephen, for all the help.  I appreciate it very much.  You got me thinking.